# How to use varargs for small logger?

Tags: c

I am looking to make a small logger to be used like this:

```
logger log;
const char* text = "World";
log.write("Hello %s", text);
log.write("Step %d", 1);
```

This is my code, which doesn't work correctly:

```
class logger
{
public:
    void write(const char* msg, ...)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen("c:/test.txt", "a");
        if(file != NULL)
        {
            va_list args;
            va_start(args, msg);
            fprintf(file, "%s\n", msg, args);
            va_end(args);
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
};
```

This is what I get:

```
Hello %s
Step %d
```

I never used `varargs` before so I am not sure if I am using it correctly.

Comment: C doesn't have classes or access specifiers. Don't just tag randomly.

Comment: It's going to be very slow if you open and close the file for every individual print.

Comment: @StoryTeller: either way, this is a C solution, not C++.

Comment: @Kobe Oh really!? And you suppose the things that the C++ standard has to say about var arg functions is immaterial!? Or will you be running your C++ code through a C compiler?

Comment: Answering the question only requires knowledge of C so I think that tagging C is appropriate. It doesn't seem worth arguing about. If there's no clear answer then just use both.

Comment: If this is C++, then don't use varargs. Consider Boost.Format. And be clear about which language you want to use.

Comment: @StoryTeller: there are more elegant ways to do this in C++, that's why I put a C tag, I wanted a C solution, even if I use a class. I am just not allowed to use std workspace in my C++ project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking that C behaves in a manner similar to Java or Python or other languages that can "splat" an array argument to a function that accepts varargs, but C isn't that sophisticated. When you pass args to fprintf, C literally pushes the value of args (a variable of type va_list) onto the stack. What you need instead is to push the *contents* of args onto the stack.

Or, instead, you could use a function that accepts a va_list as a parameter. That function is vprintf (and friends vsprintf, [vfprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vfprintf/), etc.).

You have another issue, which is that you're fprintf-ing the caller's "msg" parameter using "%s" but then apparently expecting fprintf to recursively use the result as a format string and fprintf the args too. That's not going to work. Instead just use the caller's msg as the format string.

```
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, msg);
        vfprintf(file, msg, args);
        fputc('\n', file);
        va_end(args);
```